# Loading variables from python file failed when running batch program

Tags: python, batch-file, selenium-webdriver

Ever since i'v started to load variables from separate file I encountered failure during running python programs with batch files with selenium webdriver.

lets say i have:

```
project/
│
│── project/
│   ├── schedule.py
│   └── database/
|       └── config.py
```

inside scheudle.py i got this lines:

```
from database.config import *

driver = Chrome(options=c_options)
driver.get(url)
password_field = driver.find_element_by_id('password')
password_field.clear()
password_field.send_keys(password)
```

and inside config.py i got this lines:

```
password = keyring.get_password(...)
```

the error i get:

```
password_field.send_keys(password)
{'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

**But note this**, after i'm opening the python file itself in PyCharm, everything works fine, the batch and all, even if i close PyCharm, its like its loading the vars or something...

I would love to know how to fix this problem,
Thanks.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use `import *`, makes everything ambiguous. Consider reading `PEP` guidelines https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Comment: How is this related to tag [tag:batch-file]?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried naming the imported config.py:

```py
from database import config
...
password_field.send_keys(config.password)
```

Comment: maybe your project isn't in your path ? using sys  lib:
`sys.path.append('your/project/path')`